# error in creating query string using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

when i am passing query string using anchor-tag i getting my url but problem is there processorId=51 is repeating twise 
my string is coming like that
MonthlySettlementAlgorithm/MonthlySettlementResultviewByDate?processorId=51&bankId=51&bankId=2866

but i am expected

MonthlySettlementAlgorithm/MonthlySettlementResultviewByDate?processorId=51&bankId=2866

please give me solution for this

```
+ "<li><a target='_blank'  href='/MonthlySettlementAlgorithm/MonthlySettlementResultviewByDate?processorId=' >View By Date</a></li>"

 + "<li><a target='_blank' href='/MonthlySettlementAlgorithm/MonthlySettlementResultViewByBank?processorId=' >View By Bank</a></li>"

    Jquery Code 

         $('.dropdown-menu.features li a').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('href'))
            {
                $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + selectedProcessorIds +'&bankId='+ selectedBankIds);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Set `href='/MonthlySettlementAlgorithm/MonthlySettlementResultviewByDate'` initially when you build the `a` tag in js.

Comment: i already tried this line but i am not getting exactly

Answer (score 0):

finally i get solution for this

```
 $('.dropdown-menu.features li a').each(function () {

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href) {
        var requiredArray = href.split('?');

        if (requiredArray.length > 1) {
            var tempProcString = "processorId=" + selectedProcessorIds;
            var tempBankString = "&bankId=" + selectedBankIds;
            var tempDate = "&snapshotDate=" + $('#txtDate_FirstDateValue').val();
            requiredArray[1] = tempProcString + tempBankString + tempDate;
            console.log(requiredArray[1]);
        }

        //finally updating href
        $(this).attr('href', requiredArray.join('?'));
    }
});
```